# Cant use Firebase in UITests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, xctest

I am trying to test a register viewController continues to another viewController after a succesful registration. Once this test has run i am trying to delete the user created on firebase using:

```
func removeUser() {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        user.delete(completion: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The test runs fine before i add this function to the file but after i add it to the test file and try to run tests i get:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth", referenced from:

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have succesfully used the same function in unit tests but for some odd reason this doesnt work in the ui test.

Here is the full error log:

```
    Ld /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests-Runner.app/PlugIns/WelcomeScreenTests.xctest/WelcomeScreenTests normal x86_64
    cd /Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk -L/Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -F/Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks -F/Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -F/Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/waynerumble/Desktop/tddsplitter/Splitter/Pods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Splitter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WelcomeScreenTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=11.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Splitter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WelcomeScreenTests_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Splitter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WelcomeScreenTests.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework XCTest -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Splitter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests.build/WelcomeScreenTests.xctest.xcent -lPods-WelcomeScreenTests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Splitter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WelcomeScreenTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/waynerumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fgegrycgijcewrgdrhbzitkzbsmm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WelcomeScreenTests-Runner.app/PlugIns/WelcomeScreenTests.xctest/WelcomeScreenTests

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in WelcomeScreenTests.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Update:

podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Splitter' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  def allPods
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  end

  # Pods for Splitter

    allPods

  target ‘BillTests’ do
    inherit! :search_paths
    allPods
  end

  target ‘ItemTests’ do
    inherit! :search_paths
    allPods
  end

  target ‘UserTests’ do
    inherit! :search_paths
    allPods
  end

  target ‘WelcomeScreenTests’ do
    inherit! :search_paths
    allPods
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?  Make sure to link Firebase with your test target.  Compare: [Linking error in unit test using URLRequestConvertible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34934959/2415822)

Comment: Hi yea i am and i believe i have, i have updated to show my podfile contents

Comment: so you led to me the fix which was removing inherit! :search_paths from the test target. If you want to put that as the answer ill accept it. Or do it myself in 24hrs. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the linked duplicate to mention that case, and have closed this question as a duplicate.  While the libraries are different, the main question is still the same.